# importing Adult dataset as a data frame. The data frame doesn't subset

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, rstudio, subset

I'm evaluate RStudio's subsetting features and I have a public data set for which the subset function doesn't seem to work.

The data set is the Adult dataset.
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult

I'm creating the data frame as follows:

```
adult <- read.csv("~/Resources/Test ML Data/Adult/adult.data", header=FALSE)

colnames(adult) <- c("age","workclass","final weight","education","education-num","martial-status","occupation","relationship","race","sex","capital-gain","capital-loss","hours-per-week","native-country","income")

adult[["final weight"]] <- NULL
adult[["education-num"]] <- NULL
adult[["age"]] <- ordered(cut(adult[["age"]],c(15,25,45,65,100)),labels = c("Young","Middle-Aged","Senior","Old"))
adult[["hours-per-week"]] <- ordered(cut(adult[["hours-per-week"]],c(0,25,40,60,168)),labels = c("Part-Time","Full-Time","Over-Time","Workaholic"))
adult[["capital-gain"]] <- ordered(cut(adult[["capital-gain"]],c(-Inf,0,median(adult[["capital-gain"]][adult[["capital-gain"]]>0]),Inf)),labels = c("None","Low","High"))
adult[["capital-loss"]] <- ordered(cut(adult[["capital-loss"]],c(-Inf,0,median(adult[["capital-loss"]][adult[["capital-loss"]]>0]),Inf)),labels = c("None","Low","High"))
```

Then I try to subset the data on any column.

```
adult_t <- adult[adult["sex"] != "Female", ]
```

adult_t data frame comes out to be identical to the original data frame.
I've also tried variations.

```
adult_t <- subset(adult,adult$sex != "Female")
```

Same results

---

I can subset other data sets like the wine data set. (also located on the same site)

```
wine <- read.csv("~/Resources/Test ML Data/Wine/wine.data", header=FALSE)

colnames(wine) <- c("class","Alcohol","Malic Acid","Ash","Alcalinity of Ash","Magnesium","Total Phenols","Flavanoids","Nonflavanoid Phenols","Proanthocyanins","Color Intensity","Hue","0D280/OD315 of Diluted Wines","Proline")
wine_t <- wine[wine["Magnesium"] > 100, ]
```

This works correctly.

I can't see why the adult data set isn't subsetting. I am fairly new to **R**, so any insight into what is going on here would be helpful.

I'm using Version **0.98.981** of RStudio and version **3.1.1** of R

Comment: I have no time to test it with your dataset, but here are two things that you could try: (1) replacing `adult[adult["sex"] != "Female", ]` with `adult[which(adult["sex"] != "Female"), ]` (to handle differently `NA` values), and (2) reading the csv with `adult <- read.csv("~/Resources/Test ML Data/Adult/adult.data", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` (to handle strings instead of factors)

Comment: Should have been `adult[["sex"]] != "Female"` .  Other possibilities: leading or trailing spaces in the values in the "sex" column. Try `table( nchar( adult[["sex"]] ) )`

Comment: Thanks using `adult[which(adult["sex"] != "Female"), ]` worked !!

I also utilized the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE and strip.white=TRUE` parameters in loading the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your dataset is the spaces after every comma, which are non-standard for a csv. You can solve this problem using `strip.white` from read.csv.

```
url <- "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data"
adult <- read.csv(url, strip.white = TRUE, header = FALSE)
```